# Query with many selectionsargs

Tags: java, android

I'd like to query the Database in order to retrieve the phonenumber.

Instead of using an static Array with selection arguments, i'd like to use an Array, which will be created and filled dynamically(for example the size of the array vary) during runtime.

I tried to use the following statement:

```
Cursor phones = _ctx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " IN  (?)",
            actioncids, null);
```

"actioncids"  := String[] with the selection args , contains elements from a previous query

I always get the error message:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException : bind or column index out of range handle 0x3c6540

I suppose I have to use a different expression in the Where-Clause.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your bind variables into a String array:

```
Cursor phones =     
_ctx.getContentResolver().query(
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " IN  (?)",
     new String[] { actioncids }, null);
```

Note: if you want to add several `actioncids` you need several `?`.

Hope this helps .... Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I created a new method: 'private String repeatChar(String c, int frequency)
    {
        String result = "?";
        
        for(int i = 1; i < frequency; i++)
        {
            //anhängen der Buchstaben
            result = result + " , " + c;
        }
        
        return result;
    }' and now it works , .... + " IN ( " + repeatChar("?", size) + " )" ...